# Как синхронизовать методы разных приложений?

Tags: база-данных, многопоточность, java

День добрый, уважаемые!

Есть несколько приложений, каждое из которых обращается к веб-сервису, забирает из него данные и обрабатывает. Обращаться надо периодически (данные меняются с течением дня, представьте, что это курс валюты с сайта ЦБ). Вопрос: как синхронизовать приложения так, чтобы они не сохранили нужные данные дважды? Разрешить обращаться к сервису только одному приложению нельзя.

Если бы был только один клиент, я бы сделал так: забирал бы данные, сохранял бы их в базу и кэш базы, при очередном обращении проверял нет ли уже таких данных.

Но ситуация сложнее. Сохранять данные в общей БД можно, но т.к. синхронизации нет, то нет гарантии, что клиенты не запустятся одновременно и одновременно занесут в БД одно и то же значение курса (за 15:00, например). Какие я вижу варианты:

1. Как-то залочить БД пока выполняется один из клиентов. Наподобие `lock` или `synchronized` в Джаве. Это можно сделать?
2. Грузить все в одну таблицу запросом вида `insert if unique`, а потом считывать оттуда. В принципе нормальный вариант, хотя, мне кажется, более ресурсозатратный, чем первый.
3. Сохранять в таблице индекс следующего клиента, чтобы остальные не запускались одновременно (то есть разнести их по времени).

Что скажете?

Comment: А вы не можете перед БД разместить сервис, к которому будут обращаться клиенты и который будет единолично управлять запросами на обновление данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А кто мешает сделать так.
Делаем одно приложение, которое знает, когда и как можно обращаться к внешнему сервису, как  читать и писать.

А все Ваши сервисы подключаются к этому приложению. А оно либо отдает с кеша, либо делает запрос и отдает. Эта схема решит много вопросов - синхронизацию, актуальность данных, отладку. А также, представьте, что внешний сервис поменял АПИ/адрес. При правильном подходе, все приложения даже не заметят, что внешний сервис изменился/упал/прислал заведомо неверные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Пункт 1 явно плохой идеологически, даже если вы найдёте такую возможность. Т.к. вы хотите заставить клиентов ждать. Хотя если клиентов мало, то наверное они могут и потерпеть.

Пункт 3 плохой потому что он в общем-то к 1-му приближается.

Пункт 2 - или какие-то его вариации - хороший. Примерно об этом же сказал и yozh в своём комментарии. Т.е. смысл в том чтобы клиенты не сохраняли данные напрямую, а сохраняли "реквест на сохранение данных", а дальше либо отдельный сервис, либо хранимая процедура в БД эти сохранённые реквесты разбирала и единолично определяла, что сохранять а что не надо.

"Реквест на сохранение" видимо сохраняется в таблице содержащей номер клиента, данные которые он хотел сохранить и время когда он их предоставил, я так понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

либо вы делаете проверку на уровне БД либо на уровне приложения ( напр. веб сервиса ). 
**на уровне БД:**

```
а) первичный ключ в таблице(ах)
б) триггеры
с) взаимоисключающие запросы типа: 
   insert into dest 
   select * from input where not in ( select * from dest )
```

**на уровне приложения:**

```
а) самым простым и банальным решением является добавление синхронизации методов.
б) как вариант - использование очереди заданий. где каждый клиент добавляет свое задание на обновление БД. что позволит исключить ситуации дублирования.
```

валидация на уровне приложения может негативно сказатся на производительности системы. с точки зрения производительности удобнее на уровне БД это сделать.

p.s. есть подозрение что у вас неправильно спроэктирована БД раз у вас возникла такая проблема